# Javascript advice for dynamic replacing content

Tags: javascript

I need an advice how to dynamically change HTML data.

My web page will have some form, which will call a PHP function, which I am planing to return JSON array (I can accept also other output, except raw HTML). 
Than i want the page content to be replaced with the JSON values.

The idea of that is to have the HTML code separated from the PHP function.

Can you please tell me if this is a good practice and if yes, can you please give me some example ?

Thanks in advice !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is actually a good practice - I do this every day .
See the web is fast advancing and the more we separate concerns the more flexible we get . Now here are the facts :

- With the introduction of Progressive Web Apps , creating an app shell
  (Basically a skeleton of the website without data) is recommended so
  that new data is loaded from ajax/fetch [see this link](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/architecture/app-shell)

  Imagine when you want to do a tv version of your website/webapp - you
  will only need to create an app shell where the JSON data will be
  used to fill in the data

I advocate for separation of concerns since it will be much easier to add more platform & device support since you will only be worried about the template / shell and not the data

Here is an example :

filename/url : localhost:8080/index.php

```
<?php
  $myObj->name = "John";
  $myObj->age = 30;
  $myObj->city = "New York";
  $myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
  echo $myJSON;
?>
```

Then on the client side

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.getJSON demo</title>
  <style>
  #userInfo{
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="userInfo"></div>

<script>
(function() {

  var myUrl = "https://localhost:8080/index.php";

  $.getJSON( myUrl)
    .done(function( data ) {

  /*
   {"name":"John","age":30,"city":"New York"}

  */
     var userInfo = document.getElementById('userInfo');
     userInfo.innerHTML = '<p>Name :'+ data.name +'</p>
                           <p>Age:'+ data.age+'</p>
                           <p>City:'+ data.city+'</p>';

    });

})();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please share with me some working example, to see how to do it ?

Comment: welcome , I have edited the answer and added a working example

Comment: Thanks. I have made it with AngularJS :)